# Как указать путь к статическому файлу в Django в шаблоне

Tags: python, django

Как указать путь к статическому файлу в Django в шаблоне? Данному url'у, localhost/guess/i, где i - натуральное число, соответствует данный шаблон:

```
{% if pupil.id %}
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Trying to guess</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<IMG src="что здесь указывать" width="189" height="255" alt="here must     be an image">
</BODY>
{% endif %}
```

Шаблон получает от представления pupil.id. Для каждой такой страницы есть картинки 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ... в директории static/guess/images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% load static %}
{% static 'guess/images' as static_images %}
<IMG src="{{ static_images }}/{{ pupil.id }}.jpg" width="189" height="255" alt="here must be an image">
```

На сколько я могу судить из приведённого вами примера, вы неправильно используете статику. Храните 1.jpg, 2.jpg и т.д. лучше в media.

Comment: Чем media лучше ? В документации написано хранить в static/guess/images.

Comment: Он для этого предназначен.